# How to verify background (css) image was loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, load, background-image

I have the following CSS class that I'm applying on a `<td>` tag:

```css
.bg {
   background-image: url('bg.jpg');
   display: none;
}
```

How can I tell with JavaScript/jQuery that the background image finished loading?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this is to load the image using Javascript, and then set that image as the backgroud.

For example:

```
var bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.onload = function(){
   myDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgImg.src + ')';
};
bgImg.src = imageLocation;
```

Comment: For some weird reason the onload only fires when the imageLocation actually takes some time to load, like from the web. It doesn't work in local testing with 0 loading time.

Comment: you could set a timeout for the `bgImg.src = imageLocation;`, but I'd assume most people won't be on your computer, :P

Comment: This actually has a bug when `bgImg.src` contains special characters like single and double quotes and backslashes.  Instead you should make it `'url("' + bgImg.src.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace('"', '\\"') + '")';`.  I think that should escape any url properly.

Comment: I wonder if it would be wise to set `bgImg = null;` after assigning the URL to the background image, since there is no real need for the JS object. The concern being the browser might have 2 copies and waste memory? Implementation dependent, surely.

Comment: This will try to fetch the image twice, hopefully the browser cache will prevent the second fetch from actually calling the server

Answer (score 4):

Give the class to a div with `visibility:hidden` at the initial page load. That way, it'll already be in the browser cache when you assign the class to your table cell.

Answer (score 2):

[This article may help you](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1007-jQuery-Attr-Function-Doesn-t-Work-With-IMAGE-complete.htm). Relevant section:

```
// Once the document is loaded, check to see if the
// image has loaded.
$(
    function(){
        var jImg = $( "img:first" );

        // Alert the image "complete" flag using the
        // attr() method as well as the DOM property.
        alert(
            "attr(): " +
            jImg.attr( "complete" ) + "\n\n" +

            ".complete: " +
            jImg[ 0 ].complete + "\n\n" +

            "getAttribute(): " +
            jImg[ 0 ].getAttribute( "complete" )
        );
    }
);
```

Basically select the background-image and do the check to see it's loaded.

Comment: I don't think this can be done when the background's initial state is display:none;

Answer (score 2):

@Jamie Dixon - he didn't say he wanted to do anything with the background image, just know when it's loaded...

```
$(function( )
{
    var a = new Image;
    a.onload = function( ){ /* do whatever */ };
    a.src = $( 'body' ).css( 'background-image' );
});
```

Comment: Will it work if the element on which I applied background has the property - display:none;  ?

Comment: yes, as far as I know this doesn't matter, it's just grabbing the style rules and forcing the image to preload (essentially), when it is done preloading it fires an onLoad event.

however you don't want to do this if you want to lazy load a large image (as it may slow things down)

Comment: I'm having trouble to make it work.
Here is my style: background-image: url('../Images/bg/xxx.jpg');
The a.src gives me the image location with the url('');

It seems that the onLoad is never fired. (I also tried onload)

Comment: hey thedp, I just edited my code.  it wasn't working for me, though I swear I was when I posted it.  try the new version.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with `onload` is that it fires when the data is ready, not when it is done rendering.

For one project I load a bunch of medium large images. As the images are loading one get the effect of images *“popping into existence”* in a fragmented way.

Solved this by using a combination of `onload` and [`decode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode).

As for Q: *“How can I tell that the background image finished loading?”*. It can be interpreted in several ways; but if one is looking for finished ***rendering*** this is an attack on that issue.

Simplified:

---

```js
img.onload = () => {
    some_elm.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + some_src + ')';
    img.decode().then(some_function).catch(some_function);
}
img.onerror = some_function;
img.src = some_src;
```

Where `some_function` simply checks a counter on all the images loaded, but can of course also be used for *one* image.

Guess it can easily be the overhead of `decode()` that causes it to flow nice, but have worked very well.

Have found it to work nice both for loading `<img>` elements, (using `decode` only), and backgrounds (`onload` + `decode`).

---

Then one can do anything from simply adding a class to a wrapper or add some fancy effects - for example fading in image by image in ordered fashion etc.

Also note [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode#browser_compatibility) for `decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You also can provide a function that simply replaces the img tag by the div/background so that you benefit from both the onload attribute and the flexibility of the div.

Of course, you can fine tune the code to best suits your need, but in my case, I also make sure that either the width or the height is preserved for a better control of what I expect.

My code as follows:

```
<img src="imageToLoad.jpg" onload="imageLoadedTurnItAsDivBackground($(this), true, '')">

<style>
.img-to-div {
    background-size: contain;
}
</style>

<script>
// Background Image Loaded
function imageLoadedTurnItAsDivBackground(tag, preserveHeight, appendHtml) {

    // Make sure parameters are all ok
    if (!tag || !tag.length) return;
    const w = tag.width();
    const h = tag.height();

    if (!w || !h) return;

    // Preserve height or width in addition to the image ratio
    if (preserveHeight) {
        const r = h/w;
        tag.css('width', w * r);
    } 
    else {
        const r = w/h;
        tag.css('height', h * r);
    }
    const src = tag.attr('src');

    // Make the img disappear (one could animate stuff)
    tag.css('display', 'none');

    // Add the div, potentially adding extra HTML inside the div
    tag.after(`
        <div class="img-to-div" style="background-image: url(${src}); width: ${w}px; height:${h}px">${appendHtml}</div>
    `);

    // Finally remove the original img, turned useless now
    tag.remove();
}
</script>
```