# How do you detect that a CSS image is loaded?

Tags: jquery, css, image, callback, loading

I'm using an image texture for a background (which is a repeated image), and I'm also using a sprite sheet. All of these are loaded via CSS.

I've tried using `$(window).load()` to fade in the images after load, but you can still see it **rendering/loading**.

I'm starting to think that `$(window).load()` only works for images in the **DOM**.

Is there a way to detect that a CSS image is loaded?

Comment: Your answer I believe (tldr: no): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927610/how-to-verify-background-css-image-was-loaded

Comment: I believe you can't do that via CSS. Did you try to googol or smth?

Comment: why you have "check if loaded via CSS" in title and have "jquery, callback" in tags?

Comment: how about loading the image out of view with JS and when it's done, set it as the background?

Comment: @knitevision I want to fade in the image after I detect it. Thought it was the same as callbacks.

Comment: @devJunk Can you do that for images you want to be tiled?

Comment: Yes, CSS rules apply to dynamic elements too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preloader to hide all content on your page until all elements will load.

HTML

```
 <div id="preloader">
        <div id="status"></div>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#status').fadeOut();
            $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
            $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
        })
    //]]>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#aed0de; /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index:7; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#status {
    width:400px;
    height:418px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image:url(../images/status.gif); /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    margin:-209px 0 0 -200px; /* is width and height divided by two */
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.6em;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
    color:#3d6a7c;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3);
```